# Split huge provider into multiple files

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a angular provider (https://github.com/zerodine/angular-restclient/blob/master/src/angular-restclient.js) which contains 900+ lines of code. It's getting harder to maintain the provider.

Is it a good idea to split it in multiple files and how would I do it?

I saw different approached with require (https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe) or the use of plain javascript objects.

(I want the provider to be concatenated and uglified in the build process)

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes since I consider 300 to 500 big and anything beyond that obese.

Splitting files is not hard. Split them by classes, modules, etc. Just keep to the single responsibility principle.

This has been the lamest answer I've ever given. I blame you though :)

Comment: Thanks for blaming me :) The thing is that I can't inject factories into a provider. So how do I extract the classes? As plain JS? Or is there a good angular way? Providers with empty $get method?